# How to increase the app icon size in my android device, for flutter based apps

Tags: android, flutter

Guys i am trying to increase the app icon size in my phone but for some reason it seems to occupy only limited size like this

[image]

But I want the image to take up a max size like this

[image]

Can anyone help me with this issue

Comment: what is the size of your icon?

Comment: I am sorry, but could you please tell me where can I find size of the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default size of the icons would be like this:

- 48 × 48 (mdpi)
- 72 × 72 (hdpi)
- 96 × 96 (xhdpi)
- 144 × 144 (xxhdpi)
- 192 × 192 (xxxhdpi)
- 512 × 512 (Google Play store)

You can find more about icon sizes in [here](https://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/)

There are also some icon generators like [this one](https://appicon.co/)

Comment: I will take a look at that.Thank you